# Perforce refers to a different root while editing

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec

I have the following perforce client `perforce.myClient` that contains different directories. When I open a file for edit using `/perforce.myClient/p4 edit someFile`
it fails with the following message  `/perforce.myClient/someFile is not under clients root '/my/other/perforce/client'`

I did the following to ensure that perforce is picking up the right client

```
setenv P4CLIENT perforce.myClient
```

checked to see if the root points to the correct location using `p4 client perforce.myClient`

How else can I enforce the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the [global options](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.1/manuals/cmdref/global.options.html) in your command like

```
p4 -c myclient edit -c mychangelist //...
```

Global options appear before the command name.

Comment: Hi Xavier, isnt -c the changelist number? Whne I use teh above command it expects a changelist number after -c?

Comment: Sorry, had the wrong syntax, that worked, tahnk you!

Answer (score 1):

P4CONFIG files are hugely useful for this.  Do this:

```
p4 set P4CONFIG=.p4config
echo P4CLIENT=perforce.myClient>/perforce.myClient/.p4config
echo P4CLIENT=my.other.perforce.client>/my/other/perforce/client/.p4config
```

Now your P4CLIENT will change automatically based on your working directory.

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/P4CONFIG.html